# Remove Backup-SqlDatabase progress bar when complete

Tags: powershell

I have fully working powershell 3 script that backups up an number of SQL databases. This script is called by a master script that then calls a number of other powershell scripts that do various jobs.

For each database being backed up there is the nice progress bar, but the bars never go away even through everything works and they report 100%.

I do not want to disable the progress bars completely just for then to go away when complete, though I would accept them just disappearing when the backup script is complete.

The command being call is `Backup-SqlDatabase -DatabaseObject $Database -BackupFile "$($Path)$($DatabaseName)_db_$($DateStamp).bak"` but I cannot see any switches that might help.

I doubt this is relevant but the master script is calling the backup script via `Invoke-Command` and executing it directly on the SQL server as a specific user.

Comment: hello rob I think you should check backup status for understood backup is complete or not  for see all backup check this `dir SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost\DEFAULT\Databases | Select Name, LastBackupDate `

Comment: The backups are fine and complete but how can I then remove the backup progress bar?

Comment: I have the same issue. How can we get rid of the progress bar?  I want to restore many databases at once.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be a good solution:

> $ProgressPreference=’SilentlyContinue’

I got this tricks from [here](http://www.jasonhelmick.com/2010/11/06/suppressing-the-powershell-progress-bar-2/)

Comment: Plus it doesn't actually answer the question. The OP specifically states *"I do not want to disable the progress bars completely"*.